# How can I prepend http to a url if it doesn't begin with http?

Tags: python, python-2.7, url

I have urls formatted as:

```
google.com
www.google.com
http://google.com
http://www.google.com
```

I would like to convert all type of links to a uniform format, starting with `http://`

```
http://google.com
```

How can I prepend URLs with `http://` using Python?

Comment: This is too vague. In what context are you doing this? Where are these URLs coming from, where are they stored, and where are you outputting them?

Comment: This is actually not a bad question because Python do have builtin functions to treat that correctly, like `urlparse.urlparse(my_url, 'http')` and others functions in this module

Comment: You are specifying 4 different formats. Are you sure that there is no other format?

Comment: @JBernardo Except `urlparse(my_url, 'http')` recognizes the URL as a path, not a netloc...

Comment: @barakmanos Those are the ones I noticed

Comment: Well, then there are probably quite a few others, and based on your question, the solutions that you'll be receiving might not be sufficient in order to solve the problem **in all cases**.

Comment: @larsmans For the purpose desired, just doing `urlparse.urlparse(my_url, 'http').geturl()` will suffice

Comment: @JBernardo Awesome.. It works fine except that it doesn't remove www from the url. Could you post that as a answer?

Comment: @Giri some websites will not load unless they have `www` in front of them

Comment: @JBernardo I see.. Then how about converting all links to www version. As of now some links missing www

Comment: @Giri, Then again, some sites may not load if you add `www`... I added an answer telling how to do that if you really want

Comment: @JBernardo Depends. The result is `http:///google.com`, which is not a valid URL. `urllib2.urlopen` won't process it, for example.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Python do have builtin functions to treat that correctly, like

```
p = urlparse.urlparse(my_url, 'http')
netloc = p.netloc or p.path
path = p.path if p.netloc else ''
if not netloc.startswith('www.'):
    netloc = 'www.' + netloc

p = urlparse.ParseResult('http', netloc, path, *p[3:])
print(p.geturl())
```

If you want to remove (or add) the `www` part, you have to edit the `.netloc` field of the resulting object before calling `.geturl()`.

Because `ParseResult` is a namedtuple, you cannot edit it in-place, but have to create a new object.

PS:

For Python3, it should be `urllib.parse.urlparse`

Comment: @Giri Just did that. Because the `ParseResult` is a namedtuple, you cannot edit it in-place, but have to create a new object

Comment: I'm getting syntax error in this line `path = p.path if p.netloc else or ''`

Comment: @Giri It was a copy-paste problem. removed the `or`

Comment: could you assign the first line to p variable?

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast That is not part of the original question but something you want. You could simply adapt this code changing one line or ask a new question if you are so inclined. Not sure if you should call yourself a python enthusiast if you can't do either of those and choses to downvote me...

Comment: You can make this a little more concise by using [namedtuple._replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace). (It starts with an underscore, but it's public, so don't worry).

Comment: Here's JBernardo's example with that. It's simpler if we don't try to prepend www., which strikes me as a rather odd thing to do, but I'll keep it for comparison: https://pastebin.com/QwWvVktB.

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 12):

I found it easy to detect the protocol with regex and then append it if missing:

```py
import re
def formaturl(url):
    if not re.match('(?:http|ftp|https)://', url):
        return 'http://{}'.format(url)
    return url

url = 'test.com'
print(formaturl(url)) # http://test.com

url = 'https://test.com'
print(formaturl(url)) # https://test.com
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 6):

For the formats that you mention in your question, you can do something as simple as:

```
def convert(url):
    if url.startswith('http://www.'):
        return 'http://' + url[len('http://www.'):]
    if url.startswith('www.'):
        return 'http://' + url[len('www.'):]
    if not url.startswith('http://'):
        return 'http://' + url
    return url
```

But please note that there are probably other formats that you are not anticipating. In addition, keep in mind that the output URL (according to your definitions) will not necessarily be a valid one (i.e., the DNS will not be able to translate it into a valid IP address).

Comment: `.find(x) >= 0` is more idiomatically written `.startswith(x)`.

Comment: @larsmans. I initially wrote it using `startsWith` (which obviously didn't work, cause it's not Java)... Thanks for the correction; answer revised

Comment: Can this be adapted to work with both `http` and `https` urls?

Answer (score 0):

```
def fix_url(orig_link):
    # force scheme 
    split_comps = urlsplit(orig_link, scheme='https')
    # fix netloc (can happen when there is no scheme)
    if not len(split_comps.netloc):
        if len(split_comps.path):
            # override components with fixed netloc and path
            split_comps = SplitResult(scheme='https',netloc=split_comps.path,path='',query=split_comps.query,fragment=split_comps.fragment)
        else: # no netloc, no path 
            raise ValueError
    return urlunsplit(split_comps)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you URLs are a string type you could just concatenate.

```
one = "https://"
two = "www.privateproperty.co.za"

link = "".join((one, two))
```

Comment: Never came out right when I submitted the post.